# Connecting a blind cable to electrical system

Tags: circuit-analysis, wiring, bad-wiring

I am trying to connect a blind cable, (cable that doesn't have any end point connected to the grid), to the grid. This is how electrical wiring looks like. X's are lamps. and black lines in the first image are literally just a standard cable with live, neutral and ground(I omitted ground from the images).
[image]

Schematically it looks like this:[image]

I tried connecting the left light(left X) to the grid, like this:
[image]

Apparently this is not how you do it, because the voltage at left X is just 100V and it should be 230V. What would be the correct wiring? The cables are already in place, so it is difficult for me to lay down a new one.

Comment: It is not clear what your diagrams represent and what the 'X's are. It is clear that you are not familiar with mains wiring so our advice is that you should not be seeking advice from random people on the Internet but should find someone local that is qualified to do the work. This advice, of course, is from a random person on the Internet.

Comment: Electrical loads (your lamps, for example) are always connected in parallel to the mains. Your diagram shows the lamps in series. I agree with Transistor that you should get some help, or take a free online course in basic wiring, before connecting anything to the mains.

Comment: Blind?  What does that even mean?  ROFL  Why don't you explain what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to connect another 230V load?  Yes, then use vu2nan's answer.  As in **connect in parallel**.  L to L and n to n.  You have connected it in series with the little x.  The voltage you get would be the potential of hopefully connecting a high impedance DMM in series with source and the little x,  As the junction suggests, get someone who knows what they are doing before you hurt yourself!

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. The lamps are 230V. I used the term blind, (coined just moments ago) to describe a cable with no connection to the mains on either end. Not the best naming convention, I agree. For some reason, I assumed the lamps have an internal parallel circuit. Apparently they do not. Can you recommend a book on household wiring? Not to worry, I am always wearing insulating gloves and disable the correct fuse before touching anything.

Comment: Then you wire things up at random and expect them to work.  Measure across a set of terminals.  Make up terms.  And expect an answer.  All I am is perplexed.  If you wire your lamp wrong you could put Line on metal, so I'm not worried about my safety al all!  Your on the other hand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cables are to be connected as shown in the schematic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that in the morning.

Comment: Please be careful and take help from experienced personnel!